# How to create a .command file with unity with execute privileges?

Tags: ffmpeg, unity-game-engine

In my app I'm trying to use ffmpeg through a batch file, windows works great writing .bat files, however when I write .command files on MAC the files don't open and tells me that I don't have permission.

Also when I run the command

```
chmoc u+x [.command File Path]
```

through the terminal the file works..

Knowing that when I create a new text file with the command and rename it to .command it works fine.

I write the command file in unity using File.WriteAll, is there any other way for writing the file that gives the previlage needed? knowing that I run the batch file using a process in unity.

Thank you

Comment: Please show a sample file you have generated. Also, it's a *Mac* not a *MAC* since that is a Media Access Control address. Also, I think you mean `chmod` not `chmoc`.

Comment: Just a typo sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with chmod was actually a typo